# Sort a set of points to minimize the sum of the square distances between two consecutive points

Tags: optimization, sorting

Let $P$ be a finite set of points in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Let the number of points in $P$ be $n\in\mathbb{N}$. I want to sort the points in $P$ to minimize the sum of the distances between two consecutive points:

\begin{align}
&\text{minimize}  &&\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} ||p_i-p_{i+1}||^2\\
&\text{subject to} && p_i\in P
\end{align}

Any sorting algorithm that I have looked up refers to sorting a set of scalar values, from smallest to biggest.

Comment: Sounds like the [3D version of the Travelling Salesman Problem](https://processing.org/discourse/beta/num_1202328935.html).